# Is this question appropriate?

Tags: discussion

Take a look at [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197307/zombie-pigmen-farm-in-minecraft-1-8) Minecraft question on Arqade.

Is this question appropriate? As it's asking for opinions about a spawner, and not about some specific questions, I don't think it meets the standards of Arqade. Any opinions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is **not** asking for opinions. It's asking for a specific thing i.e. the most efficient Zombie Pigman farm.

Therefore it's totally acceptable, and I'm not sure why you feel otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just asking for some opinions if I should flag it or not.

Comment: The most efficient mob grinder can be objectively determined. If whatever you're asking can be objectively determined then you're good.

Comment: That said, it's not a very good question, as it shows zero effort to solve his problem on his own.